# How to create an image of Ubuntu HDD in Windows?

Tags: windows-8.1, disk-image, ubuntu-18.04

I have an HDD with installed Ubuntu 18.0.4 with ext4 file system.
Now I need this drive for other purposes but I want save this Ubuntu installation.

So I want to create an image of this HDD, save the image somewhere, use the drive for other purposes and then restore the image some later

Is it possible to perform the described operations in Windows 8.1?
Please note that Windows does not recognize the Ubuntu drive properly, so the drive has no letter, but any software that I tried to use can create HDD images that have drive letters in Windows.

Comment: Any reason a bootable backup won't work? Clonezilla would probably be a great option here and wouldn't care about windows

Comment: My answer is about the question title regardless of it being a good idea or not. Hint: It's not, I agree with @JourneymanGeek . It's always preferable to do it from outside of any installed OS.

Comment: *Is it possible to perform the described operations in Windows 8.1?* Of course. You may use any software which can copy/backup a physical drive (sector-by-sector copy), not a logical volume. *any software that I tried to use can create HDD images that have drive letters in Windows.* Select "Physical drive" option instead volumes.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Your answer is fine. Just trying to figure out if mine would be ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Software like [Macrium Reflect](https://www.macrium.com/) and many others can do backups of Linux partitions. Drive letter is not required at all.

But whether or not you'll be able to restore the partition in a "bootable" state depends on more that just that partition. Macrium Reflect allows doing a backup of a single partiton + MBR (BIOS/Legacy) or a single partition + the EFI partition (UEFI).

Is it worth the time and effort? It depends. Generally there's no point in keeping an installation. Backing up personal files and reinstalling at a later date may save time and give a better end result.